# Reactjs, redux authorization logout issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have issue with authorization.

I have SPA written in ReactJS with Redux.
I am using Axios for Ajax request and I want handle any ajax request via axios and use interceptor which can logout if response status is 401.

SPA stores info about authorization in redux store.

I don't know how to dispatch action from function which is not component.

Now I handle it with deleting cookie with token and hard page reload (I don't like this solution).

I can dispatch logout action from any component connected to redux store but not from function and I don't want handle status 401 in every request manually.

Could you help me?

here is some simplyfied code

myAjax.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const ajax = axios.create({
   baseURL: API_URL
});
ajax.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
     return response;
}, function (error) {
    //here I want to dispatch action for logout
    if(error.status == 401){
      cookie.remove('auth', { path: '/' });
      window.location.reload();
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
export default ajax;
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers.js';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware
        )
    )
}
```

reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userAuthorization from './reducer_auth';
import preferences from './reducer_preferences';
import productCatalogue from './reducer_product_catalogue';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
form: formReducer,
    preferences,
    userAuthorization,
    productCatalogue
});
export default rootReducer;
```

reducer_auth.js

```
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import {
    REQUEST_LOGIN,
    RECEIVE_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    RECEIVE_LOGIN_FAILED,
    DO_LOGOUT
} from '../actions/actions_auth';
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isAuthorized: false,
    isLoggingIn: false
};
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case REQUEST_LOGIN:
            return { ...state, isLoggingIn: true };
        case RECEIVE_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            const { id_token, expires } = action.authorization;
            let cookieConfig = {
                path: '/'
            };
            if(expires){
                cookieConfig.expires = new Date(expires * 1000);
            }
            cookie.save('auth', id_token, cookieConfig);
            return { ...state, isLoggingIn: false, isAuthorized: true };
        case RECEIVE_LOGIN_FAILED:
            return { ...state, isAuthorized: false };
        case DO_LOGOUT:
            return { ...state, isAuthorized: false };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import configureStore from './configureStore';
import routes from './routes';
const store = configureStore();
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('app'));
```

routes.js

```
export default (
    <Route>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Homepage} />
            <Route path="settings" component={SettingsPage} />
            <Route path="product_catalogue" component={ProductCatalgueList} />
            <Route path="product_catalogue/new" component={ProductCatalgueAdd} />
            <Route path="product_catalogue/:id" component={ProductCatalgueDetail}>
                <Route path="edit" component={ProductCatalgueEdit} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Route>
);
```

app.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LoginPage from '../components/login_page';
import { doLogout } from '../../actions/actions_auth';
class App extends Component{
    logout(){
        const {dispatch} = this.props;
        dispatch(doLogout());
    }
    render(){
        const { isAuthorized } = this.props;
        if(!isAuthorized) return <LoginPage />
        return (
            <div>
                here i can dispatch logout, but not in ajax interceptor
                <button onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Logout</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
    const { isAuthorized } = state.userAuthorization;
    return {
        isAuthorized
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

action_auth.js

```
function doLogout(){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(
            {
                type: DO_LOGOUT
            }
        )
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can't you just import the dispatcher in your myAjax.js and fire the DO_LOGOUT action from there?

Comment: if I call DO_LOGOUT from myAjax then action will execute but not append to component where appended store is used. Action do deleting cookie and change store state. In this case cookie is deleted but store is not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the store to the `myAjax` component.

For example:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { doLogout } from '../../actions/actions_auth';

const ajax = axios.create({
   baseURL: API_URL
});

export function configureAjax(store) {     
  ajax.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
     return response;
  }, function (error) {        
    if(error.status == 401){
      cookie.remove('auth', { path: '/' });
      // use the store to dispatch the logout action
      store.dispatch(doLogout());
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
}

export default ajax;
```

And in your application entry point just call the `configureAjax` function

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import configureStore from './configureStore';
import routes from './routes';
import { configureAjax } from './myAjax'
const store = configureStore();

configureAjax(store); //Here you configure your ajax requests to use the store

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and here is my solution:

1. Set a listener in your app.jsx in method componentDidMount
2. Dispatch the customized event
3. Once the listener detect the customized event, dispatch the logout action;
4. app.js Code:

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener("logoutEvent", () => {
       this.props.loginAction.clearUserInfo()
     })
   }
   ```
5. myAjax.js

   ```
   const clearEvent = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
   clearEvent.initEvent('logoutEvent', true, true);
   document.dispatchEvent(clearEvent)
   ```